# import / overwrite database SQlite for Android app

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, import

I got some problem with an import of an existing database (Sqlite).
The export works fine, but when I transfer the code to the import-version nothing happens! No error - but no effect as well!

I want the user to transfer his/her data to a new smartphone. He shall copy the old database in the new smartphones download directory. 
After the code has run, the new database isn't overwritten. The database is still empty. I checked it in the ´DB browser for Sqlite´

I hope you can help me! Here's two versions of my code. The try-block is different.

First try:

```
private void importBackupDatabase(){
    readyToImport = true;

    //DataBackup
    File exS = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);// storage location of backup database
    FileChannel backupChannel= null;
    String backupName = "steps.db"; // file name, inside of download directory
    File backupDB = new File(exS, backupName);// erstelle File aus downloadorder und der datei /downloads/steps.db

    //TransferBackupTo
    String databasePath;
    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17){
        databasePath = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";
    }else{
        databasePath = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
    }

    File destinationDir = new File(databasePath);//directory

    FileChannel destinationChannel = null; // file channel to manage new db location

   File destinationDB = new File(destinationDir, "steps.db");//file

    try{
        backupChannel = new FileInputStream(backupDB).getChannel(); // file channel to manage backup location

        FileInputStream testInput = new FileInputStream(backupDB);

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(destinationDB);
        destinationChannel = out.getChannel();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        ByteBuffer bbuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer);
        int transferLength;

        while ((transferLength = testInput.read(buffer)) > 0)
        {
            destinationChannel.write(bbuffer);
        }

        destinationChannel.force(true);
        destinationChannel.close();
        backupChannel.close();

        Database.getInstance(context).close();
    }catch(IOException e){
        logger.severe("An error as occured. Overwritung DataBase canceled!");
    }
}
```

Second try:

```
  private void importBackupDatabase(){
    readyToImport = true;

    //DataBackup
    File exS = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);// storage location of backup database
    FileChannel backupChannel= null;
    String backupName = "steps.db"; // file name, inside of download directory
    File backupDB = new File(exS, backupName);// erstelle File aus downloadorder und der datei /downloads/steps.db

    //TransferBackupTo
    String databasePath;
    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17){
        databasePath = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";
    }else{
        databasePath = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
    }

    File destinationDir = new File(databasePath);//directory

    FileChannel destinationChannel = null; // file channel to manage new db location

   File destinationDB = new File(destinationDir, "steps.db");//file

    try{
        backupChannel = new FileInputStream(backupDB).getChannel(); // file channel to manage backup location

        FileInputStream testInput = new FileInputStream(backupDB);

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(destinationDB);
        destinationChannel = out.getChannel();

        backupChannel.transferTo(0, backupChannel.size(), destinationChannel);
        backupChannel.close();
        destinationChannel.close();

        Database.getInstance(context).close();
    }catch(IOException e){
        logger.severe("An error as occured. Overwritung DataBase canceled!");
    }
}
```

Thank a lot for your time! :)

Comment: And? Is the code executed? Does the new file exist? Are you opening that particular file?

Comment: when the user installs the app on a new phone the database is created (with empty tables,...). Then the old database should be imported on a button click. But nothing happens. The code doesnt occures errors but the db is still empty.